# Show last submitted value in search box

Tags: php, html

I have a text box in an HTML form where the user will input some information and press submit. This data will be submitted to the same page, so I want to show in the text box the last submitted value.

I was trying this:

```
<input name="srq" type="text" id="search_box" <?php if($_GET["srq"]) echo 'value="'.$_GET["srq"].'"'; ?> />
```

But that will turn "'hello'" into "\'hello\'". What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution may be to turn off the magic_quotes_gpc in php settings or other one is to use stripslashes in $_GET["srq"]

```
<?php if($_GET["srq"]) echo 'value="'.stripslashes($_GET["srq"]).'"'; ?>
```

I presume you understand how unsecured is that?

Comment: No I don't understand how unsecured is that. Why is it unsecured?

Comment: Never display something (*especially* when it comes from the user) without using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). If you write that, the user will be able to go to `/?srq="><script>steal_user_history_and_send_to_my_email_address()</script><"`.

Comment: So what would be the secure way to do it?

Comment: Shoud I use `htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_GET["sqr"]))`?

Comment: @jsoldi, yes, every time you display something on a page, use `htmlspecialchars()`. Every time you take a string from somewhere and use it to compose a MySQL query, use `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Don't rely on magic quotes or on slashes functions.

Comment: Rule number 1. Never trust user's input. Try to search for `<script type='text/javascript'>alert('test');</script>` Especially after you add the stripslashes. As @rdineiu suggest, it's good idea to use htmlspecialchars.

Comment: If there's no way to get rid of those slashes by turning `magic_quotes_gpc` off, then yes, `htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(...))` will work. The preferred way would be to turn off magic quotes.

Comment: I strongly suggest `htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(...))` even with `magic_quotes_gpc` turned off.

Comment: @RRStoyanov, well, with `magic_quotes_gpc` off, the slashes will be correctly escaped and will appear as intended on the page. If the user searches for \, they will see \.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to suggest using of `htmlspecialchars` anyway. So, just to wrap up all those comments. If `magic_quotes_gpc` is ON, suggestion is `htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(...))`. Bug if `magic_quotes_gpc` is OFF, than suggestion is `htmlspecialchars(...)`

Comment: I was aware of SQL injection dangers, but never thought about HTML injection. Will have to review my whole code!

Comment: You may wanna read about [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Comment: @jsoldi, good! You should be. Treat everything as the user is evil and is out to get you. You may only relax a little when the data doesn't come from the evil user.

Comment: And again... Rule number 1 > Never trust user's input :)

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'value="' . htmlspecialchars($_GET['srq']) . '"'
```

And don't add slashes automatically. If you need to insert something in the database, escape it with the db escape function (such as `mysql_real_escape_string()` for MySQL) instead of relying on slashes.

Answer (score 0):

use the [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) function when outputting the value.

Answer (score 0):

you have magic quotes = On

[use get_magic_quotes_gpc](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) to check if they are on and then use [stripslashes](https://www.php.net/stripslashes) to remove the quotes